# c# chartarea backimage sizing

Tags: c#, charts, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to put a background image for a chartarea in windows form app.
I succeeded to put the backimage but I want the chartarea to be exactly the same size as the backimage.
I tried to size the chart area using the inner plot position, I think I managed to correctly size the chart area to be equal to the image size, however I still have a problem : the backimage is slightly shifted (see attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b0Zu.png)). I want my backimage to be like ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5HRt.png)).
Can someone help me Sizing the chart area and the image correctly? note that the image will be used to plot chart points, the width of the image corresponds to x = [0.0005 - 0.2 ] and the height is for y = [0.0005 - 0.05].
Here is my code :

```
        ChartArea ca = Chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        ElementPosition cap = ca.Position;
        ElementPosition ipp = ca.InnerPlotPosition;
        // chartarea pixel size:
        Size CaSize = new Size((int)(cap.Width * Chart1.ClientSize.Width / 100f),
                                (int)(cap.Height * Chart1.ClientSize.Height / 100f));

        // InnerPlotArea pixel size:
        Size IppSize = new Size((int)(ipp.Width * CaSize.Width / 100f),
                                 (int)(ipp.Height * CaSize.Height / 100f));
        //Previous lines are used to get the size of the inner plot in pixels to adjust my image size.
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackImage = "MyImage.png";
        //Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0.1, 0.02);
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 0.2;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0.00005;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "h/gT^2";
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0.00005;
        Chart1e.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 0.05;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "H/gT^2";
```

Thanks in advance,

Mohamad Hmedi.

Comment: It is hard to see what you have done wrong when we can't see what your code is. I have several posts here that will letyou find out/convert the [innerplotarea](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+innerplotarea); are you sure the size is wrong or is it the position? Did you set the chart position to be fixed, ie non-automatic?

Comment: @TaW Thank you for your comment. I used you technique to get my innerplot size in pixels then I modified my image size to match it. I will edit my post and add my code so you can have a look on what I did. I am still having the same problem on a shifted backimage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding BackImageWrapMode :

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Scaled;
```

By using the wrapmode scaled, the backimage will be stretched to fit within the bounds of the chart area.